# jQuery Related Selects pass additional param

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here's the most basic code of it (i'm using [this](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-related-selects/))

```
$("form").relatedSelects({
        onChangeLoad: 'datasupplier.php',
        selects: ['stateID', 'countyID', 'townID', 'villageID']
    });
```

i need to pass several more parameter for some reason. my usual ajax code is something like this

```
$.post("ajax/template.php", {myparams: $("#myparams").val(), action: "SEARCH_MEMBER_DETAILS" },
                    function (data){
                        var returnCode = data.returnCode;
                        if (returnCode == "1"){
                            $("#data").val(data.name);
                        }

                },"json");
```

question is, how do I send the params like myparams and action to the jQuery Related Selects code?

i tried something like

```
 $("form").relatedSelects({
            onChangeLoad: 'datasupplier.php',
                data: {action: "SEARCH_MEMBER_DETAILS"},
            selects: ['stateID', 'countyID', 'townID', 'villageID']
        });
```

but it seems the additional params are not sent

Comment: I don't see any direct way to achieve this, but by modifying the `relatedSelect` script slightly you may be able to do something

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know whether it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relatedScripts plugin does not provide any facility to manipulate the ajax request.

But it is possible to alter it slightly to achieve the requirement.

If you are ready to make a change in the plugin do the following steps

In the `populate($caller,$select,o)` method of the plugin make the following change

```
beforeSend: function(){
    return o.onLoadingStart.apply($select, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0));
},
```

It is now `beforeSend: function(){ o.onLoadingStart.call($select); },`

Then change your script like

```
$("#example-2").relatedSelects({
    onChangeLoad : 'datasupplier.php',
    loadingMessage : 'Please wait',
    selects : ['stateID', 'countyID', 'townID', 'villageID'],
    onLoadingStart : function(jqxhr, settings) {
        console.log('st', arguments, settings.url);
        settings.url += '&t=tttt'
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AU6GG/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I've went through the documentation of the plugin and seems that there's not a way to achieve what you need.

If you don't want to extend the plugin and implement the functionality  by yourself, you can try by creating the parameter inside the onChangeLoad and pass them as GET parameter like this:

```
$("form").relatedSelects({
        onChangeLoad: 'datasupplier.php?myparams='+$("myparams").val()+'&action=SEARCH_MEMBER_DETAILS',
       selects: ['stateID', 'countyID', 'townID', 'villageID']

});
```